# jQuery show div on hover with image map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imagemap

I have an image map that I want to show a new div when I hove over the hotspots. It starts with a default listing of text but once I mouseover the hotspots, I want that to change out to the corresponding div's. I'm using the following code and am getting no joy:

```
$(".office-default").mouseover(function () {
    var elementId = "#office-" + $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
    $(elementId).removeClass("hidden");
});

$(".office-default").mouseout(function () {
    var elementId = "#office-" + $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
    $(elementId).addClass("hidden");
});
```

Here's the entire code:
http://jsfiddle.net/leadbellydesign/jR6pa/1/

I've done tons of searches and have come up with nothing helpful. I don't want to change images, I just want to show div's.

Comment: There is no ID attribute for the div ".office-default".

Comment: Okay, when I add the ID "office-default" when I mouse out of that, the initial image and text disappears. So, at least I'm getting some sort of action. Thanks!

Comment: Your code is saying that when you hover over the entire image map, create a var and remove the hidden class from it. You need to apply this code to each section. Something like this: `$(".office-default div").mouseover(function () {
    var elementId = $(this).attr("id");
    $(elementId).removeClass("hidden");
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to fix the space below the divs, but this should work

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/mjUw8/)

```
$("area").hover(function () {
    $office = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".office-default > div").addClass("hidden");
    $($office).removeClass("hidden");
}, function(){
    $(".office-default > div").addClass("hidden");
    $("#office-1").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

To fix the spacing issue, update your `.office-default` CSS:

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/5ESbh/)

```
.office-default {
    background:#444;
    padding:5px 15px 0;
    width: 80%;
    height:150px;
}
```

Comment: One last question. How difficult would it be to leave the information available for copy and paste until you hover over another area in the map? I'm having a hard time troubleshooting the extra space if it disappears every time I mouse out.

Comment: Thanks! I should have posted that I'd figured that out. :)